# Gather MySQL data using multiple variables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select data from a table using multiple variables.

I have two different tables which I would like to use, the first being "masterdata" which contains "Slot1", "Slot2" and "Slot3" and the other table which is called "playerdata" and contains the column "ID".

I have already got a query which selects and sets each of the slots into a variable however I am now trying to select all of the rows of data from playerdata, which has an ID which is the same as either Slot1, Slot2 or Slot3. I am not sure on how to do it within a query and even if there is a way to do this, I would be grateful if someone could explain this.

Thank you.

Preview of data selection:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you're mixing up database with table term? Show your approach to the task.

Comment: @ConsiderMe Yes, I was; sorry. I need to show three rows with the ID which matches either Slot1, Slot2 or Slot3, For example: Slot1 = 23, Slot2 = 43 and Slot3 = 59. I need it to show three rows where the ID is, 23, 43 and 59.

Comment: Attach sample data and expected result in your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM playerdata p
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM masterdata WHERE p.id IN(slot1, slot2, slot3))
```